# Sumar valor a una celda si se cumple una condición

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una hoja que tiene estas columnas y filas de ejemplo:

```
|   COLOR   |   A COLOR   |   REALIZADO   |
 Rojo        Verde            SI
 Azul        Amarillo         SI 
 Amarillo    Rojo             SI 
 Azul        Verde            NO
```

Y en otra hoja tengo la siguiente estructura

```
|   COLOR   |   SALIENTE   |   ENTRANTE   |
```

Lo que quiero es que en la segunda hoja, cada vez que se genera una fila dentro de la primera hoja, calcule por cada color cuantos salieron y cuantos entraron.

Es decir, en el ejemplo dado, la hoja 2 quedaría

```
|   COLOR   |   SALIENTE   |   ENTRANTE   | 
 
 Rojo          1              1
 
 Azul          1              0
 
 Amarillo      1              1
```

Si ven, paso lo siguiente:

1. La fila uno, que era de color rojo paso a verde por lo que en la hoja dos, en la fila del rojo sumo 1 a saliente
2. La fila dos, que era azul paso a amarillo por lo que en la hoja dos, en la fila del color azul sumo 1 a saliente
3. La fila tres, que era de color amarillo paso a rojo por lo que en la hoja dos, en la fila de color amarillo sumo 1 a saliente, y en la fila de color rojo sumo 1 a entrante

Pero todas estas cosas pasan unicamente si en la columna **REALIZADO** de su respectiva fila se encuentra el valor **SI**. Por ejemplo en la ultima fila **REALIZADO** tiene **NO** por lo que no se suma nada.

Como podría realizar una query que haga esto? Nunca hice nada en google sheets, entonces las cosas que fui probando no dieron mucho resultado.

Comment: Hoy día Google Sheets es una poderosa herramienta si la combinas con [Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/home). Para este caso concreto, podrías escuchar los cambios de la Hoja A, y cuando éstos ocurran lanzar un script que recoja los datos en determinada parte de esa hoja, efectúe el cálculo que sea y guarde el resultado en la Hoja B. Hablo de poderosa herramienta porque mediante los scripts puedes hacer cualquier cosa interactuando con cualquier servicio de Google (como enviar un email, crear una entrada de Calendario, guardar un archivo en Drive, etc).

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa con el verde? ¿No debería tener un 0 en entrante y un 1 en saliente?

Comment: Si Elier, estaba dando ejemplos y no me di cuenta de poner ese. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hace falta Query, puedes hacer lo siguiente:
Llamaremos la primera hoja 'Hoja1', y la segunda 'Hoja2'.

Conforme a los datos que suministras, asumiremos que en la primera hoja, los datos están organizados así (desde A1:C5):

```
COLOR | A COLOR | REALIZADO

Rojo | Verde | SI

Azul | Amarillo | SI

Amarillo | Rojo | SI

Azul | Verde | NO
```

SOLUCIÓN:

En la segunda hoja, coloca los títulos manualmente en el rango A1:C1:
COLOR   SALIENTE    ENTRANTE

Y en el rango A2:C2 (ATENCIÓN, SOLAMENTE EN ESTAS 3 CELDAS) insertarás las siguientes fórmulas:

A2:

```
> =UNIQUE(Hoja1!A2:A)
```

B2:

```
> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",countifs(Hoja1!$A:$A,$A2:$A,Hoja1!$C:$C,"SI")))
```

C2:

```
> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",countifs(Hoja1!$B:$B,$A2:$A,Hoja1!$C:$C,"SI")))
```

Listo... Sin importar el tamaño de la matriz de la Hoja1, tus datos de la Hoja2 se calcularán automáticamente!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que también necesitas los colores que estén en la columna B de tu hoja 1, necesitas 2 fórmulas en tu hoja 2:

La primera es para sacar la lista de colores, yo la he puesto en la celda A2:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPONER(split(JOIN("||";UNIQUE('Hoja 1'!A2:A);UNIQUE('Hoja 1'!B2:B));"||")));1;VERDADERO())
```

Esta fórmula creará una lista ordenada alfabéticamente, de valores únicos, de todos los colores que haya en la columna A y B de tu hoja 1.

La segunda fórmula en tu Hoja2, la pones en B2, y arrastras a la derecha, y hacia abajo, para contar los colores entrantes y salientes:

```
=CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO('Hoja 1'!A$2:A;$A2;'Hoja 1'!$C$2:$C;"SI")
```

Un ejemplo de cómo funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**IMPORTANTE:** Si aumenta la lista de colores, la columna A en tu Hoja2 se actualizará sola, pero los cálculos de ENTRANTE Y SALIENTE no. Tienes que arrastrar manualmente la fórmula hasta que estén todos los colores calculados. En el vídeo de arriba fíjate que al meter `Morado` y `Azul`, luego manualmente he arrastrado para tener las cuentas de todos.

Espero que puedas adaptar esto a tus necesidades.

De todas formas, he subido el archivo a Google Drive por si quieres echarle un vistazo:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CLq93oVEfOhVYJ3awhw0eWccEnH2p1UkLvxo97Wtrew/edit?usp=sharing